# How do I define stdin of a child process with Node's `child_process.exec`?

Tags: node.js, stdin, child-process

I want to pass a `stdin` value into [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback). How do I do that?

For `execSync` it's pretty straightforward;
`execSync('myScript', {input: stdin})`, but the docs don't clarify how to define `stdin` on `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

It may seem counter intuitive, but since `exec` is async, you can actually define `stdin` later in your code with `child.stdin.write`;

```
var child = exec(myScript, function(err, result) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});
child.stdin.write(stdin);
child.stdin.end();
```

When you define `child.stdin.write` in this way, you also have to manually call `child.stdin.end()`.